# Hudson + get the build status

Tags: hudson, hudson-api

I have a job 'A' running with hudson and Ant. If the current build status is Fail, I need to run the build "A" after 3 hours again. If the current build status is Success, nothing to do.

Is there any way to automate this?

Answer (score 0):

you could use a [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) in which you would trigger the usual job twice:

- one on demand
- one only if the first instance fails.

[image: Trigger]